# Plugins in Vue's Single File Components

Tags: vue.js

I wrote a plugin:

```
var MyCoolVuePlugin = {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.doStuff = function() {
            console.log("I'm a useless plugin")
        }
    }
}

export default MyCoolVuePlugin;
```

In my `main.js`, where my frontend starts and the Vue instance is created, I included my plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import MyCoolVuePlugin from './plugin';

Vue.use(MyCoolVuePlugin);

window.vApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: Router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
});
```

And then in my `App.vue`, I have some stuff like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Is Anybody There</h1>
    <some-other-component />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SomeOtherComponent from "./components/SomeOtherComponent";

export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        "some-other-component": SomeOtherComponent
    },
    data() {
        ...
    },
    mounted() {
        // How do I access my Vue plugin
        // I can do:
        vApp.doStuff();
        // Or I can do:
        this.$parent.doStuff();
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

How do I access my Vue plugin as shown in the `mounted` function of App.vue? When I ask "how do I" I mean what is the correct, recommended way? Perhaps I'm failing at searching but so far I've been unable to find documentation related to accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your plugin is installed using `Vue.use()` it calls the install method of the plugin in which you are adding a method to the `prototype` of `Vue`

This allows you to access this method in any component using `this.doStuff()`

So you can access it in a mounted hook as

```
mounted() {
    this.doStuff();
}
```

I recommend that you name the property or method you are attaching on the prototype with a `$` prefix.

So `Vue.prototype.$doStuff` can be accessed in any component as `this.$doStuff`. This is just a convention.

Comment: I swear I tried this and it didn't work. I just tried it again and now it is. That's quite frustrating but also very helpful! Thank you for your answer.